# Collision detection in cycles

Tags: python, animation, drivers

I want an object to do something if another object collides with it, very similar to the "Collision"-logic-brick in the bge. Is there any way to use a similar method in another engine?
I am aware of a python command collision. Maybe it can integrated into a driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about the blender logic operations but this is what I can do in this case:

- **Add a driver for the operation you want to apply to the object.**
- **Add a distance variable and set the object to itself and the other object.**
- **Add a custom property and call it margin which will be the margin of the object (the distance in which the object will interact from the origin point).**
- **Add this custom property to a single property variable.**
- **Type "ternary conditional operator" like this in the expression.**
- **Now when ever the "Cube.001" touch the "cube" the scale will change to 2 instead of 1 (and of course you can change the operation)**

[image: Driver]

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: Is this also pssible with a particle system? Meaning a particle touches the obkect and the object transforms.

Comment: So you want the action to be applied when the particle system touch the object?

Comment: Exacly: A particle hits, an action is performed.

Comment: I can't think of a solution other than scripting,But if you want to apply this action based on the location of the particle in a material or something,you may want to try dynamic paint.

Comment: There are great solutions over here: There are some great solutions here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71289/using-overlap-to-check-if-two-meshes-are-intersecting/